# How to acquire permission for opening spreadsheet using openById or openByUrl

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to store user entered data to other spreadsheet so I declared some global variables for calling sheets of other spreadsheet and called spreadsheet using openByUrl function. It worked.

After this I tried adding custom menu to my current spreadsheet from where I have to take user entry and tried to add menu to menu bar onOpen but execution failed. Stating error -
**Jun 18, 2023, 4:58:57 PM  Error   Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
at unknown function**

And when I comment out variable declaration it runs.

Codes are as under -

```
var edUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qTUKifG4qsk2quRok4XIMYnPO-gzcJlECgCmjxnclaQ/edit";
var ssData    = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(edUrl);
var wsClients = ssData.getSheetByName("Clients");
var wsCliPrj  = ssData.getSheetByName("CLI-PRJ");
var wsEstData = ssData.getSheetByName("EstimateData");
var wsPrjEst  = ssData.getSheetByName("PRJ-EST");
var wsEstTc   = ssData.getSheetByName("EST-TC");
var wsItems   = ssData.getSheetByName("Items");


function onOpen(e){
  menu();
}


function menu() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('GHAR');
  menu.addItem('My Menu Item', 'myFunction');
  menu.addToUi();
}


function myFunction(){
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1").setValue("Hello");
}
```

This is the error shown.
[Error Required Permission image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrkX4.png)

I want to add custom menu and designate some functions to those menu in which it will read and write to different spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onOpen(e)` function runs in a restricted context where methods that require authorization are not available. `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` requires authorization, and will thus cause `onOpen(e)` to error out.

You are not calling `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` in `onOpen(e)`, but it appears in the assignment of a [global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable) which gets evaluated *before* `onOpen(e)` runs.

You can avoid the issue by moving all global variables inside an initializer function or by using a getter. For sample code, see [How to use global variables while avoiding permission errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65150194/13045193)